# declaring class objects in a switch and later using that variable outside the switch

Tags: c++, oop, switch-statement

Is there a way to work around this?Im declaring  class objects  in a switch statement and later using that variable outside the switch, it only works if i put the rest of my code in each case which isnt very efficient.Heres my code

```
switch (shape)
{
case 'q':
{
    Quad geo(a,b,c,d);
}
break;
case 'r':
{
    Rectangle geo(a,b,c,d);
}
break;
case 't':
{
    Trapezoid geo(a,b,c,d);
}
break;
case 'p':
{
    Parrelogram geo(a,b,c,d);
}
break;
case 's':
{
    Square geo(a,b,c,d);

}
break;
default:
    break;
}

 geo.print();//obviously wont work
```

Comment: Do the types 'Quad', 'Rectangle', etc inherit from the same base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have an `IPrintable` interface, like this

```
struct IPrintable
{
    virtual ~IPrintable() {}
    virtual void Print() = 0;
};
```

Then, derive your types `Quad`, `Rectangle`, etc from `IPrintable`, i.e. implement that interface. Then your code looks like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<IPrintable> pShape;
switch(shape)
{
    case quad:
       pShape.reset(new Quad(...));
    case rect
       pShape.reset(new Rect(...));
}
if(pShape)
    pShape->Print();
```

Of course, if the common functionality is more than print, you can add those functions to the interface as well. Also take a look at the visitor pattern. It may or may not be of help to you depending on the specifics of your problem.

Comment: `unique_ptr` would be a better choice in this case (why do people always use `shared_ptr`??), as the object is not *shared*, but the rest of the code would be exactly the same +1

Comment: @David: I agree with you. Edited.

Comment: Need to ensure that the stored pointer in pShape is not-null prior to `pShape->Print()` call.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. `geo` can only have one type at compile time, and it cannot change at runtime.

You could do something similar with dynamic allocation and polymorphism, but it might not be the best solution to your problem.

With the knowledge that Quad is the base class of the others, the following might be a usable solution:

```
Quad* geo = 0;
switch (shape) {
case 'q':
    geo = new Quad(a,b,c,d);
    break;
case 'r':
    geo = new Rectangle(a,b,c,d);
...
default:
    break;
}
if (geo) geo->print();
delete geo; // Ok if geo is 0.
```

This solution is not particularly pretty, mainly because it uses raw pointers and `new` and `delete` directly. A more polished version would use the `Factory`pattern, returning a smart pointer.

Comment: the problem with this is that i have a overidden print function so its only called the quad print function if i enter a different shape

Comment: @user954004: Am I understanding that `print` is not a virtual function? It should be.

Comment: would just declaring the base class or all derived class' virtual work?

Comment: You should prefer using smart pointers to manage the memory. If `print` throws, you will leak the object. +1 anyway.

Comment: @user954004: All overrides must be virtual, but, declaring the base member function as `virtual` will have that effect, so you only *need* to do it at that level (I prefer to declare it at all levels as a form of *documentation* it will be virtual whether the keyword is present in the derived types or not, so why hide it?)

Comment: seems to have no effect, just adding virtual to the header file is the way to do it right?

Comment: @user954004: Look at Armen's answer

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's what I wrote just after the code snippet. I wanted the code to be as close to the one in the question as possible.